# change the class of the currently selected tab on next and previous button

Tags: jquery

I want to change the css class of the currently selected tab on the click of the next and previous button. The next and previous click is working fine. However I also want to change the css class of the currently selected tab.

```
$(".next-tab").click(function () {
            var selected = $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected");
            $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);

        });

        $(".prev-tab").click(function () {
            var selected = $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected");
            $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected", selected - 1).addClass("current");
            var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
            $("#tab-div li a:not(first)").removeClass("current");
            $("#tab-div li a:first").addClass("current");
        });
```

Any advice or suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with jquery ui tabs.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

you could use the method `.andSelf()`

http://api.jquery.com/andself/

```
.andSelf().addClass("current");
```

Comment: It's just a suggestion, I'd like you to prepare a jsFiddle. (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I checked the andSelf() but no luck